# Difference between "use" and passing a parameter to controller function

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function, silex

I don't have a specific problem, just looking to deepen my understanding of what's going on with Silex and with some new-ish PHP features in general. This is based off the code samples on the "usage" page of the Silex documentation:

```
$blogPosts = array(
    1 => array(
        'date'      => '2011-03-29',
        'author'    => 'igorw',
        'title'     => 'Using Silex',
        'body'      => '...',    );

$app->get('/blog/{id}', function (Silex\Application $app, $id) use ($blogPosts) {
    //do stuff
}
```

**Questions**

- What is the difference here between passing the `$app` and `$id` as **parameters** to the function, and **use**-ing the `$blogPosts` variable?
- Could `$blogPosts` also have been passed as a **parameter** to the function?
- Also, I more commonly see `use ($app)`. What is the difference between **use**-ing the `$app` and passing it is a **parameter**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with silex and everything to do with "some new-ish PHP features".
You are creating an anonymous function (also called a closure), reusable several times with different `$app` and `$id` values, BUT with only the same `$blogPosts` value.

```
<?php
$a = "a";
$b = "b";
$c = function ($d) use ($b) {
    echo $d . "." . $b . PHP_EOL;
};
$b = "c";
$e = function ($d) use ($b) {
    echo $d . "." . $b . PHP_EOL;
};

$c($a); // prints a.b, and not a.c
$e($a); // prints a.c
```

Here, i'm building a function with $b, and once it is build, I use it with variables that do not have to be named the same way the function's argument is named.

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this but your example is definitely helpful. It's interesting to note then that "use" will reference the value of $b as it exists at the time the use statement is *declared*, not caring about when the function containing the "use" statement was *called*. So "use" kind of defines an environment for the closure it's attached to. I'm assuming that if, under `$b="c";`, you had put another function `$e = function ($f) use ($b) { //same stuff };`, then calling `$e($a)` would print out "a.c."  Am I getting this?

Comment: Very good answer, but not excellent as it does not address ALL the OP's questions. OP has several important questions...

Comment: Well you can submit changes to this answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this makes it more transparent

```
<?php
$a = "a1";
$b = "b1";
$f = function ($x) use ($b) {
    echo $x . $b;
};
$f($a); // prints a1b1

// now let's change values of $a and $b
$a = "a2";
$b = "b2"; //--> won't be used as $b was 'b1' when declaring the function.
$f($a); // prints a2b1
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The use allows to import variables from the parent scope into the closure scope.

It will allow the function get() to call your closure with the appropriate param $blogPosts imported from the parent scope.